# Visual Basic Memory Info

Tags: vb.net, memory, hardware

Is there any way in visual basic to display any of this information about memory(like in the link below)?

Something like Module Name,Serial Number,Module Type,Memory Speed,Timings etc. ?

[image: http://s13.postimage.org/q9vl8wsud/mem.jpg]

Comment: The WMI class [`Win32_PhysicalMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394347(v=vs.85).aspx) seems to fit your needs. There are plenty of tutorials, snippets, etc, about accessing WMI from .NET if you search for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Damien_The_Unbeliever stated your best bet would be to look at the [`Win32_PhysicalMemory WMI Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394347.aspx). You can experiment around WMI by downloading the [WMI Code Creator from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572), it will generate code in C#, VB.Net and VB script which you can run through the program and see what the results are.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are asking is how to retrieve information about hardware components (namely main memory) using VB.

Please see [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=508069) thread on VB forums on some example of accessing hardware information.

You might also be interested in [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=303113) a bit more as it seems to cater to your needs a bit more.

Good luck.

Comment: I want the information from that image about memory/RAM,or any of theme that can be retrieved using vb.